# SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() en Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Este PROCEDURE está hecho en el motor de base de datos MSSQL y necesito pasarlo a ORACLE 11g:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_User]
   @Username NVARCHAR(20),
   @Password NVARCHAR(20),
   @Email NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username)
   BEGIN
          SELECT -1 AS UserId -- Username exists.
   END
   ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email)
   BEGIN
          SELECT -2 AS UserId -- Email exists.
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
          INSERT INTO [Users]
                    ([Username]
                    ,[Password]
                   ,[Email]
                    ,[CreatedDate])
          VALUES
                    (@Username
                    ,@Password
                    ,@Email
                    ,GETDATE())

          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS UserId -- UserId
          --No he encontrado un sucedáneo para esta línea...       
 END
END
```

Ya transformé la mayoría del cuerpo de la Procedure, sólo me falta la parte indicada de SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual version de oracle?

Comment: **Version 11g**

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar la versión **11g** no tiene columnas de tipo `IDENTITY` así que imagino que esto en particular lo habrás resuelto con una`SEQUENCE` y un `TRIGGER`. Algo como esto:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA (
  ID           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE TABLA ADD (
  CONSTRAINT TABLA_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE SEQUENCE TABLA_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLA_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLA 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT TABLA_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Y entonces: ¿Cómo obtener el último `ID` insertado en la tabla, que en definitiva es lo que hace un `scope_identity()`? Lo que se puede es obtener el último `id` insertado de la siguiente forma:

```
insert into TABLA (...) values (...)
returning id into v_id;
```

Comment: Y dentro del Procedure, ese v_id, lo declaro antes?

Comment: Si debes declararla, `v_id` es una variable que recibirá el último `id` luego del insert

Answer (score 0):

Queda hasta el momento así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_User
   @Username VARCHAR2(20),
   @Password VARCHAR2(20),
   @Email VARCHAR2(30)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username)
     BEGIN
      SELECT -1 AS UserId -- Username exists.
     END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email)
     BEGIN
      SELECT -2 AS UserId -- Email exists.
     END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Users
                (UserId
                ,Username
                ,Password
                ,Email
                ,CreatedDate)
      VALUES
                (SEQ_USERS.NEXTVAL
                ,@Username
                ,@Password
                ,@Email
                ,SYSDATE)

      --SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS UserId -- UserId
      --No he encontrado un sucedáneo para esta línea...
      RETURNING ID INTO v_id;
      SELECT v_id AS UserId; --Algo así?
  END
END
```